# How do i refresh the label in python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label, refresh

i'm pretty new to python and i just created a small code to make sort of a click counter with the interface being made in Tkinter. My problem is that each time i press the button with the coin it adds 1 to the coin counter underneath, that's what it is supposed to do but for some reason it can add 1 coin only once, after clicking the first time it doesn't work anymore, clicking the button does nothing.
I appreciate any help.

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

window.maxsize(800,800)
window.minsize(800,800)
window.title("coins")
window.iconbitmap("coin.ico")
window.config(background="#7693c2")

coin = 0

def addcoin():
    coin =+ 1
    label.config(text=coin)


frame1 = Frame(window,bg="#7693c3")
frame2 = Frame(window,bg="#7693c2")

CoinImage = PhotoImage(file="coin.png").zoom(10).subsample(13)
CoinImage2 = PhotoImage(file="coin.png").zoom(10).subsample(60)

AddCoinButton = Button(frame1, borderwidth= 30, image=CoinImage, bg="#93aacf", command=addcoin)
AddCoinButton.grid(column= 0, row=0 ,padx=180,pady=40)

canvas = Canvas(frame2, width = 100, height= 100, bg="#7693c2", bd=0, highlightthickness=0 )
canvas.create_image(50,50, image = CoinImage2)
canvas.grid(column=0,row=0)

label = Label(frame2, text=coin,bg="#7693c2",font=("ASI_System",50))
label.grid(column=1,row=0)


frame1.grid(column=0,row=0)
frame2.grid(padx=300,column=0,row=1,sticky="w")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, you have a typo in `addcoin()`, the augmented addition operator is `+=`, not `=+`. Your code is assigning the value `+1` every time.

Second, the `coin` variable you defined is a *global* one (defined at the top
level, outside any 'def' scope), but when you try to access `coin` inside the
`addcoin()` function, python assumes you want a local variable, and it will
complain that it's being referenced before assignment. To tell python that you
want the global variable, use the `global` statement.

You can change you addcoin function like this:

```
def addcoin():
    global coin
    coin += 1
    label.config(text=coin)
```